# C# Modification of IEnumerable while Enumerating with ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, enumeration

This is something that I was exploring to see if I could take what was

```
List<MdiChild> openMdiChildren = new List<MdiChild>();
foreach(child in MdiManager.Pages)
{
    openMdiChildren.Add(child);
}

foreach(child in openMdiChild)
{
   child.Close();
}
```

and shorten it to not require 2 `foreach` loops.

**Note** I've changed what the objects are called to simplify this for this example (these come from 3rd party controls). But for information and understanding
`MdiManager.Pages` inherits form `CollectionBase`, which in turn inherits `IEnumerable`

and `MdiChild.Close()` removes the open child from the `MdiManager.Pages` Collection, thus altering the collection and causing the enumeration to throw an exception if the collection was modified during enumeration, e.g..

```
foreach(child in MdiManage.Pages)
{
   child.Close();
}
```

I was able to the working double `foreach` to

```
((IEnumerable) MdiManager.Pages).Cast<MdiChild>.ToList()
.ForEach(new Action<MdiChild>(c => c.Close());
```

Why does this not have the same issues dealing with modifying the collection during enumeration? My best guess is that when Enumerating over the List created by the ToList call that it is actually executing the actions on the matching item in the `MdiManager.Pages` collection and not the generated List.

**Edit**

I want to make it clear that my question is how can I simplify this, I just wanted to understand why there weren't issues with modifying a collection when I performed it as I have it written currently.

Comment: My thought is that because it's supplying a callback, each thread can be prepared with an argument to one item (thus iterating over all) before any of them are invoked; thus when the callback executes, you've already iterated over the enumerable.

Comment: @Tejs: This is incorrect; there's no multithreading going on here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your call to `ToList()` is what saves you here, as it's essentially duplicating what you're doing above. `ToList()` actually creates a `List<T>` (a `List<MdiChild>` in this case) that contains all of the elements in `MdiManager.Pages`, then your subsequent call to `ForEach` operates on *that* list, not on `MdiManager.Pages`.

In the end, it's a matter of style preference. I'm not personally a fan of the `ForEach` function (I prefer the query composition functions like `Where` and `ToList()` for their simplicity and the fact that they aren't engineered to have side-effects upon the original source, whereas `ForEach` is not).

You could also do:

```
foreach(child in MdiManager.Pages.Cast<MdiChild>().ToList())
{
    child.Close();
}
```

Fundamentally, all three approaches do exactly the same thing (they cache the contents of `MdiManager.Pages` into a `List<MdiChild>`, then iterate over that cached list and call `Close()` on each element.

Comment: yea, I was just playing around with it. I think this answers the question the closest.

Comment: Conceptually, I think `ForEach()`-style methods are underrated, since many types of collections could fairly easily permit modifications within a such a method which would be harder within a `foreach` loop; that would be especially true if the `ForEach` method passed a "cursor" object with a `Current` property as well as `Delete`, `AddBefore` and `AddAfter` methods [the cursor object could be reused continuously throughout the `ForEach` call].  An operation like deleting all items from a list that meet some criterion could be O(N) with the above interface, but with `IList<T>` it's O(N^2).

Comment: @supercat: How are you arriving at O(N^2)?

Comment: If one implements a "PurgeForAll" using the idiomatic approach of using `Remove` to take out items as one passes through the loop, each removal will require all items after it to be shifted.  After writing my comment, I realized that one could, using `IList<T>`, read out each item and then store it into a new spot, but that doesn't convey what one is doing as well as would calling `Remove` on items to be deleted and doing nothing with items that aren't (leaving such handling to the underlying `List` implementation).

Comment: On some implementations of `IList<T>`, if one has a list of 10,000 items and wants to have ten items in the middle removed, calling `Remove` to take out those ten items would be faster than reading every item in the list by index and storing it to the spot where it should go.  On other implementations, reading and rewriting every item would be faster.  An implementation which exposed a `PurgeForAll(Func<T,Bool>)` method could implement it in whatever fashion would best fit its internal representation.

Comment: @supercat: Indeed, I see your point. I still don't think the lambda approach is (idiomatically) the best, but there's no reason you couldn't have something like this: `foreach(var item in list.AsMutableEnumerable() { ... }` or something like that. It would essentially expose an `IEnumerable<IMutator<T>>`, where `Mutator<T>` would provide the functions (`Delete`, `InsertBefore`, `InsertAfter`, etc.) you're looking for.

Comment: @AdamRobinson: If a class exposes an `UpdateAll(Action<IMutator<T>>)` method, it can reasonably specify that the underlying object may not be used in any way (even for reading), except via the `IMutator<T>` until the `UpdateForAll` has completed.  Such behavior would be unexpected with an `IEnumerable<T>`, and gets especially bad if an enumerator gets abandoned without being disposed.

Answer (score 1):

You're mostly right.

`ToList()` creates a copy of the enumeration, and therefore you are enumerating the copy.

You could also do this, which is equivalent, and shows what you are doing:

```
var copy = new List<MdiChild>(MdiManager.Pages.Cast<MdiChild>());

foreach(var child in copy)
{
    child.Close();
}
```

Since you are enumerating the elements of the `copy` enumeration, you don't have to worry about modifying the `Pages` collection, since each object referece that existed in the `Pages` collection now also exists in `copy` and changes to `Pages` don't affect it.

All the remaining methods on the call, `ForEach()` and the casts, are superfluous and can be eliminated.

Comment: It not only creates a copy, it does all the copying before the `.ForEach` runs.

Comment: Yes, that obscures it, which is why I wrote it differently.

Comment: You'll need to call `MdiManager.Pages.Cast<MdiChild>()`, since it only implements `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Adam - actually, why cast to `((IEnumerable)MdiManager.Pages)` then?

Comment: @codekaizen wouldn't it still need to be `new List(((IEnumerabe) MdiManager.Pages).Cast<MdiChild>` since there is no constructor for List that takes a CollectionBase, or for that case even just IEnumerable. Also I know that I can do this without all of the craziness, just trying to do it and then had a question.

Comment: @msarchet - yes, there is a ctor which does. It is `List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)`. Why do you cast `MdiManager.Pages` to `IEnumerable`, if it is already an `IEnumerable<MdiChild>`?

Comment: @codekaizen because it isn't an IEnumerable<T> it's just an IEnumerable

Comment: @codekaizen: I think you may have my comment backwards; the OP says that `MdiManager.Pages` implements `IEnumerable` (not `IEnumerable<T>`). You need the call to `MdiManager.Pages.Cast<MdiChild>()` in order to produce an `IEnumerable<MdiChild>`, which is what the `List<MdiChild>` constructor expects.

Comment: @msarchet - then why do you need the `((IEnumerable)MdiManager.Pages)` cast? In your example, you do a `openMdiChildren.Add(child);` without casting, which leads me to belive that it is `IEnumerable<MdiChild>`

Comment: @Adam - Something then isn't correct: you can't do `openMdiChildren.Add(child);` if it was only `IEnumerable`, you'd need to cast to `MdiChild`. Further, if it is the case that `Pages` is only `IEnumerable`, he casts `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable` - clearly superfluous.

Comment: no it isn't an `IEnumerable<MdiChild>` the only reason that the `openMdiChildren.Add(child) works is because it can cast the `Object` to a `MdiChild`.

Comment: @codekaize, yes the IEnumerable is Superfluous, and is only there to clarify the interface and why the Cast<MdiChild> is present.

Comment: @codekaizen: I think the OP's code might not be exactly as it is in his app (he said he simplified it), as there's no type on `child` in the `foreach`. He's likely specifying it as `MdiChild child`, which is legal in C# on an object that implements `IEnumerable`, though it will fail at runtime if the cast fails.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the `ToList()` method you're actually enumerating the `MdiManager.Pages` and creating a `List<MdiChild>` right there (so that's your `foreach` loop #1).  Then when the `ForEach()` method executes it will enumerate the `List<MdiChild>` created previously and execute your action on each item (so that's `foreach` loop #2).

So essentially it's another way of accomplishing the same thing, just using LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

You could also write it as:

```
foreach(var page in MdiManager.Pages.Cast<MdiChild>.ToList())
    page.Close();
```

In any case, when you call ToList() extension method on an IEnumerable; you are creating a brand new list.  Deleted from its source collection ( in this case, MdiManager.Pages ) will not affect the list output by ToList().

This same technique can be used to delete elements from a source collection without worrying about affecting the source enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, the culprit is ToList(), which is a *method* returning a *copy* of the items as a List, thus circumventing the problem.